# Python Tkinter Entry() Calculations

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator, python-3.4

I am currently trying to build a GUI calculator using python with the help of tkinter. I have managed to set up all of my buttons and they interact with my entry() bar when I press the button (e,g: Press button 5 and 5 appears into the entry()).

The only thing left to do is actually perform the mathematical equations that appear in the entry(). For example, if I enter 5 + 5 * 2 into the entry bar, how would I make the answer appear into the entry() after it's updated? So basically all I'm asking is someone to help me make this happen!

I have provided the code below and a screenshot of the calculator. Also please don't report this as a duplicate or flag this question as a post, (I'm reasking this question because I got no help on my last one so please help a young python programmer out!). Also I'm asking you not to provide me with links because I've read every possible link on tkinter there is to read and still have no clue what I'm doing.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#ACTIONS:
def clear():
    #Action: Clears the entry().
    txtDisplay.delete(0,END);
    return;

def update_Entry(inputValue):
    #Updates the entry when a button is pressed.
    currentText = num1.get();
    update = num1.set(currentText + inputValue);

#Parent Window.
root = Tk();
root.title('Calculator ++ [1.7.2]');
root.geometry('350x450');

#Main entry.
num1 = StringVar();
txtDisplay = Entry(root, textvariable = num1, relief=RIDGE, bd = 10, width=33, insertwidth = 1, font = 40, justify=RIGHT);
txtDisplay.place(x=15, y=10);
txtDisplay.focus();

print(txtDisplay.get())

#Buttons:
zeroButton = Button(root, text='0', width=20, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command=lambda:update_Entry('0'));
zeroButton.place(x=17,y=382);
oneButton = Button(root, text='1', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command=lambda:update_Entry('1'));
oneButton.place(x=17, y=302);
twoButton = Button(root, text='2', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command=lambda:update_Entry('2'));
twoButton.place(x=100, y=302);
threeButton = Button(root, text='3', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command=lambda:update_Entry('3'));
threeButton.place(x=182, y=302);
fourButton = Button(root, text='4', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command=lambda:update_Entry('4'));
fourButton.place(x=17, y=222);
fiveButton = Button(root, text='5', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command=lambda:update_Entry('5'));
fiveButton.place(x=100, y=222);
sixButton = Button(root, text='6', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command=lambda:update_Entry('6'));
sixButton.place(x=182, y=222);
sevenButton = Button(root, text='7', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command=lambda:update_Entry('7'));
sevenButton.place(x=17, y=142);
eightButton = Button(root, text='8', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command=lambda:update_Entry('8'));
eightButton.place(x=100, y=142);
ninthButton = Button(root, text='9', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command=lambda:update_Entry('9'));
ninthButton.place(x=182, y=142);

decimalButton = Button(root, text='.', width=8, height=3, bg='powder blue', command=lambda:update_Entry('.'));
decimalButton.place(x=182, y=382);
equalButton = Button(root, text='=', width=8, height=8, bg='Lightgreen', command=lambda:update_Entry('='));
equalButton.place(x=264, y=307);
plusButton = Button(root, text='+', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command=lambda:update_Entry('+'));
plusButton.place(x=264, y=222);
minusButton = Button(root, text='-', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command=lambda:update_Entry('-'));
minusButton.place(x=264, y=142);
multiplyButton = Button(root, text='x', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command=lambda:update_Entry('*'));
multiplyButton.place(x=264, y=66);
divideButton = Button(root, text='÷', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command=lambda:update_Entry('/'));
divideButton.place(x=182, y=66);
clearButton = Button(root, text='Clear (CE)', width=20, height=3, command = clear, bg='Orange');
clearButton.place(x=17, y=66);

#Locks the parent windows size.
root.maxsize(350,450);
root.minsize(350,450);

#Parent window's background color:
root.configure(background = 'black');
root.mainloop();
```

***Screenshot:***

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: To note, you don't need semicolons at the end of your lines in Python. Read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to learn to format Python like an expert.

Comment: @Kupiakos You would need them, if you had more than one statement per line...

Comment: @ChristopherWallace You shouldn't be doing that in the first place.

Comment: @Kupiakos It is just a style, it is for sure not the most important thing, in my opinion.

Comment: @ChristopherWallace Definitely not the *most important* thing, but considering OP's a beginner, it makes sense that he just doesn't know about this. Better to be introduced to the proper style sooner rather than later, before bad habits hold.

Comment: Yeah the whole semi-colins thing has become a bad habit honestly because im programming with javascript on the side and the semi colins have gotten into my head. But yeah thanks for the heads up @Kupiakos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something this simple, try having this as the `command` for your `equalButton`:

```
def evaluate():
    currentText = num1.get()
    try:
        num1.set(str(eval(currentText)))
    except SyntaxError:
        num1.set('<ERROR>')
```

Comment: Thanks this code actually worked for me and helped me out. Just one final thing, i just want to know what does the except syntaxerror: statement do?

Comment: @PamalMangat It makes it so that if the `eval` [throws an exception](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) when trying to evaluate the string, it will catch the exception and show the user instead of crashing the whole program. For example, try entering `2` then `+` then `=`.